# find current Controller name and action name when user send a request to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

i create a attribute for authorize user . for authorize user i need `Controller` name and `Action` name when use send a request to them .

for example :

this is my action :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Pemission("Add News Role")]
    public async Task<ReturnResult> AddRole(RoleDto model, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await mediator.Send(new CreateRoleCommand { RoleName = model.Name }, token);

            if (result.Success)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            return BadRequest(result.ErrorMessage);
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

i need write the code of authorize in this attribute `Pemission` .

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public sealed class PemissionAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public PemissionAttribute(string name)
    {
        _name = name;

    }
    public string Name => _name;


    public async Task FindControllerName()
    {

    }
}
```

now i need to find `Controller` and `Action` name in this Attribute .

how can i find them ???

Answer (score 1):

Change to also inherit from *IAuthorizationFilter* and within the method OnAuthorization you can retrieve the information you're looking for route data.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System;

public sealed class PemissionAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public PemissionAttribute(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public string Name => _name;

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var action = context.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var controller = context.RouteData.Values["controller"];
    }
}
```

Comment: now i need use it in constructor and i nust pass it `AuthorizationFilterContext` in `OnAuthorization` . how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @Kianoush can you inject it?

Comment: Per the question @Darkonekt posted... if you need it in the constructor you could inject it.  Here is an implementation that might work:  https://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=626